# SSH auth to the Active Directory environment

Tags: windows, active-directory, ssh, windows-server-2016

I'd like to know how you do it in your environment. My environment consists mainly of Linux machines. Authentication is via SSH keys. Additionally I have a small Windows environment (Win2k16 Std.) with Active Directory domain controller. This requires you to have an additional account. Is it possible to authorize users with SSH keys to the Active Directory environment? I would also like to configure OpenSSH on them so that linux users would find it easier to connect to a machine and restart the service. How about user privileges? Do any of you have similar environment setup? How to distribute these keys to AD?